# Additional class for.sub-menu UL?

Tags: menus, walker

This code returns my WordPress menu:

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'header-menu') ); ?>
```

What's the easiest (non-JS) way of adding additional class to all .sub-menu ul dropdowns of this menu?

I was thinking about add_filter() for wp_nav_menu but I'm afraid it will point all wp_nav_menus and I want to add these classes only to this particular one. Also, custom walker sounds a bit like an overkill.

What would you recommend?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  Because WP already adds proper CSS classes for if a menu has child and or sub menu that has parent.  If this is not what you're looking for and you need something more customized, then I am afraid custom walker is your best bet.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name

Comment: @splashingpixels - OOCSS.